# Borrar datos cada cierto tiempo

Tags: sql-server

tengo un tabla creada en SQL Server el cual tiene los siguiente datos:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogData](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fechahora] [text] NULL,
    [descripcion] [text] NULL,
    [servidor] [text] NULL,
    [horaCaptura] [time](7) NULL,
    [fechaCaptura] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Esta tabla ya contiene datos, pero esta vinculada a una aplicacion desarrollada en Python, mis usuarios hacen uso de esta tabla una vez al dia y guarda mas de 14000 registros en un dia, por lo cual en un mes ocupara mucho espacio en el HDD, y quiero formular un `Procedimiennto almacenado` que me elimine estos registros cada 90 dias, no he logrado hacerlo ya use `DATEADD` de igual manera ya intente con una eliminacion simple de fechas pero eso es lo que no quiero porque seria muy tedioso lo que tengo del `procedure` es esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sp_ProcesoDiario
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tiempo date = DATEADD(day,90,fechaHora)
--DELETE FROM LogData WHERE fechaCaptura <= GETDATE();
  DELETE FROM LogData WHERE @tiempo >= GETDATE();

END
```

De antemano se los agradeceria mucho.    :)

Comment: No me queda claro, quieres eliminar los registros cuya fechacaptura tengan una antiguedad mayor a 90 días?

Comment: si asi es, pero despues de unas vueltas ya lo he resuelto.

Comment: Ok, te dejo igual mi respuesta.Saludos.

Comment: Si, te agredezco la ayuda de todas maneras :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Santiago, es un problema sencillo si usas la función [`DATEADD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql), te paso la lógica, tu incorporala luego al `SP`

```
DECLARE @Now    DATETIME

SELECT  @Now    = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))

DELETE FROM LogData WHERE fechaCaptura < DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Now)
```

Algunos comentarios

- Es preferible usar una variable `@now` para el `GETDATE()`, de esta forma puedes conservar una único valor si necesitás reutilizarlo. Por ejemplo: si tienes varias operación dónde registres una fecha de ejecución, suele ser preferible que todas tengan una misma fecha.
- El `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))` simplemente es un truco para quitar la parte de la hora de la fecha, lo que va a tener sentido cuando la usemos para calcular desde que fecha vamos a depurar.
- Por último usamos [`DATEADD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) con el valor negativo de los días para que apartir del día de hoy calculemos cual es la fecha máxima a depurar.

Comment: Si de hecho  me ayude con tu respuesta y pude armar uno :)

Answer (score 1):

Di muchas vueltas por internet y encontre maneras de usar mejor el codigo `dateadd` y con ayuda de la respuesta de ***@Patricio Moracho*** logre armar un codigo que si me funciono:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sp_EliminacionDias90
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @lintUltimoRegistro int
    DECLARE @ldtFechaDiaAnterior datetime
    SET @ldtFechaDiaAnterior  = dateadd(minute,-5, getdate())

    SELECT @lintUltimoRegistro = Max(id) From LogData
    WHERE CONVERT(char(10), getdate(), 112) = CONVERT(char(10), @ldtFechaDiaAnterior, 112)

    DELETE FROM LogData WHERE CONVERT (char(10), getdate(), 112) = CONVERT (char(10), @ldtFechaDiaAnterior, 112)

END
```